# Why my stringstream can't work with jthread?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

I want to write an integer to a `stringstream` in another thread. I tried to do that in a `jthread`,  but the `stringstream` seems not getting anything. If I turn to use `thread`, everything works well. Would you please help me about why this problem happens, and is there any way to analyze problems like this?

Here's an example piece of code, I tried to write integers to `stringstream` inside a `jthread` in the 2nd and 3rd blocks, but it didn't work. Writing integers to `stringstream` inside a `thread` instead, in the 4th and 5th blocks can work.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // write to stringstream
    stringstream sout1;
    sout1<<1;
    cout<<sout1.str()<<endl;

    // write to stringstream in jthread, capture by reference
    stringstream sout2;
    jthread t2([&sout2]{
        sout2<<2;
    });
    cout<<sout2.str()<<endl;

    // write to stringstream in jthread, passing by parameter as pointer
    stringstream sout3;
    jthread t3([](stringstream* sout3){
        *sout3<<3;
    }, &sout3);
    cout<<sout3.str()<<endl;

    // write to stringstream in thread, capture by reference
    stringstream sout4;
    thread t4([&sout4](){
        sout4<<4;
    });
    t4.join();
    cout<<sout4.str()<<endl;

    // write to stringstream in thread, passing in parameter as pointer
    stringstream sout5;
    thread t5([](stringstream* sout5){
        *sout5<<5;
    }, &sout5);
    t5.join();
    cout<<sout5.str()<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1


4
5
```

Comment: Perhaps the threads doesn't run until after you output the contents of the string streams? Remember that generally you have no control over when threads run. Try to add a small delay between the thread creation and the output and see what happens.

Comment: You have race between main thread and jtreads: `t2` `t3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to have valid data in the stringstream you must `join()` the thread **before** you read from the stringstream, this doesn't change between `thread` and `jthread`.

`jthread` automatically `join()` the thread in the **destructor**, this happens at the **end of scope** while `thread` instead calls `std::terminate()` at the end of scope if it wasn't joined, this is the main difference.

Comment: Fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/Eo3TxGssn

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very clear. Can I say like, if I want to call a function concurrently from `main()`, and I want to use output from that function, then I shouldn't use `jthread`s, because c++ won't ensure to call my `jthread` before executing any other lines in the `main` function?

Comment: @junshi356 you can use `jthread`, just remember to `join()` it before you use its output, don't rely on the "auto joining" feature.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a thread and immediately joining it is logically equivalent to sequential, or synchronous, operation:

```
stringstream sout4;
thread t4([&sout4](){
    sout4<<4;
});
t4.join();
cout<<sout4.str()<<endl;
/* observable effect same as:
 * sout4<<4;
 * cout<<sout4.str()<<endl;
 */
```

So for your operations 1, 4, and 5, the order is well defined, writing to stream is always finished before reading.

For the operations 2 and 3 it is not the case, because your `jthread`s are joined when their destructors are called, so in this case when `main` function returns.

You don't have the control over when the code inside the thread will be actually run (without using any synchronization techniques), the only guarantee you have is that `cout<<sout2` is executed before `cout<<sout3`. `sout2<<2;` and `*sout3<<3;` can be scheduled by the operating system at any time between `cout<<sout1` and the end of `main` scope.